# How do I make a more sophisticated "Roller"?

Tags: c#, silverlight

How do I make a more sophisticated "Roller"?

I am  looking for a good example of a percentage roller in Silverlight.  (someone told me that they were called rollers)

The little default BusyIndicator is nice but I have a lot going on in the backgroud for a particular app and because of this, I want one of those rollers that give a percentage of how much time the use can expect to wait.  I already have a way of determining what sort of percentage is going on.  In other words, I know what sort of data to send the roller.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: No, they are simply called Progress bar, because they display the work progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ProgressBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.aspx) control and override the ControlTemplate to make it look the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to change custom `BusyIndicator`. Here are couple of articles that may help you:


[Custom Busyindicator style in Silverlight 4](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/busyindicator.aspx)

[Ajax-style Style for Silverlight BusyIndicator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233329/ajax-style-style-for-silverlight-busyindicator)


And there is a lot of other nicely created styles for this Control. Try to google it.

Regarding `ProgressBar` take a look at [The ProgressBar control in Silverlight](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/The-ProgressBar-control-in-Silverlight-2.aspx).